# Automatically generating bib file for a (book) collection

Tags: bibliographies

How can one automatically create a bib file for a book collection?  That is, a separate entry (@incollection) for each chapter of the book (which are written by different authors).

A few weeks ago, I was able to create a RIS file for the following MIT Press title, which I was able to import in Zotero to create a bib file automatically.

https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/gameful-world

Unfortunately, I do not remember how and where I was able to create the RIS file.

Today, I need to do the same for another MIT Press title (https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/models-bounded-rationality-volume-3) but cannot recall what I did it for Gameful World.

I have tried Google Scholar, MIT Press site, Amazon, Google Books, Microsoft Academic but all of these sites create ONE citation for the book and NOT separate citation entries for each chapter in the collection.  I have also tried the various LIBRARY databases available from two major US research universities.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question may be off-topic here as you are basically asking for a software to generate bibliography files from some arbitrary source, which seems to be unrelated to the TeX side.

Comment: Maybe you used a site like http://www.ottobib.com/ or https://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/

Comment: Hi @TeXnician, thanks for your comment.  I tagged this with "bibliography."  While I agree that this is not directly a TeX issue, it does affect the workflow of using TeX/LaTeX.  I reckon that this issue will affect most if not all writers of research papers, who use TeX/LateX, at some point in their career.  Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: Hi @albert, thanks for your comment.  The sites you cited create a single citation entry for the book, which is something that all the other sites I mentioned also allow.  What I need are "@incollection" entries for each chapter of the book (how I wish I had written down how and where I did it earlier :).  Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rediscovered what I did for The Gameful World—I used JSTOR to create the RIS file.

The following is a stable URL for the book: 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1287hcd

I selected multiple chapters and then used "Export Selected Citations" to export the citataions as RIS file, which I then imported into Zotero to subsequently create a well-formatted bibtex file.

Of course, JSTOR works if the the particular book is in their collection.

In general, it seems that JSTOR provides superior search and citation capabilities (cf. other databases including Google Scholar and Microsoft Academic).